# Chrome extension to open a new popup url on button click in chrome browser popup window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am tring to open a new popup url in chrome extension pop up on the onclick event of a button. In my case I have a page which will display two buttons on startup. This has been set in the useropt.html page

useropt.html

```
<script src="scripts/usmanager.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="btn_wrap_inner">   
        <button class="btn" id="signin">Sign In</button><br /><br />
        <button class="btn" id="signup">Sign Up</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

The JS file usnmanager.js has js code which has code to open a new popurl url in the popup window on the onlick event of the buttons above.

usnmanager.js

```
function btn_clicked(tgtUrl) {
    if(tgtUrl == "signin") {
        var manager_url = "signin.html";
        chrome.tabs.query(
        {
            currentWindow: true,
            active : true
        }, function(openselection) {
              chrome.browserAction.setPopup({
                  popup: manager_url
           });
        });
    } else if(tgtUrl = "signup") {
        var manager_url = "signup.html";
        chrome.tabs.query(
        {
            currentWindow: true,
            active : true
        }, function(openselection) {
              chrome.browserAction.setPopup({
                  popup: manager_url
           });
        });
    }
}

document.addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector('#signin').addEventListener('click', btn_clicked('signin'));
  document.querySelector('#signup').addEventListener('click', btn_clicked('signup'));
});
```

But when I am clicking either of the button the popup window is not loading the new popup page as set. Please let me know what have I done wrong

Comment: Why are you doing the `tabs.query`? You seem to be completely discarding the result.

Answer (score 0):

I would not try to pass the string in the event handler but use an attribute of the clicked button

```
function btn_clicked() {
  var id=this.id; 
  if(id == "signup") {
```

Also in you code you test `signup` twice and you only add the event handler when you click something. Instead you likely want

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
```